# can we classify text using SVM classifier in python-TextBlob?

Tags: python, svm, text-classification, textblob

```
>>> train = [
   ('I love this sandwich.', 'pos'),
   ('this is an amazing place!', 'pos'),
   ('I feel very good about these beers.', 'pos'),
   ('this is my best work.', 'pos'),
   ("what an awesome view", 'pos'),
   ('I do not like this restaurant', 'neg'),
   ('I am tired of this stuff.', 'neg'),
   ("I can't deal with this", 'neg'),
   ('he is my sworn enemy!', 'neg'),
   ('my boss is horrible.', 'neg')
   ]
>>> test = [
    ('the beer was good.', 'pos'),
    ('I do not enjoy my job', 'neg'),
    ("I ain't feeling dandy today.", 'neg'),
    ("I feel amazing!", 'pos'),
    ('Gary is a friend of mine.', 'pos'),
    ("I can't believe I'm doing this.", 'neg')
    ]
>>> from textblob.classifiers import NaiveBayesClassifier
>>> cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(train)
>>> cl.classify("This is an amazing library!")
'pos'
```

The above code is for classifying a text using Python by using NaiveBayesClassifier. Similarly i have used MaxEntClassifier, DecisionTreeClassifier. Now i want to know are there any classifeirs other than the ones which i have mentioned for classifying in python. please let me know!!!